# Git always merge without a fast-forward, except for when pulling?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-config

Is there a way to have git always merge without a fast-forward, except for when pulling?

Following a nice git-flow, I like keeping my branch history (easier to remove features, etc later on), so I have set my config to **never** fast-forward when merging, like so:

```
git config --global merge.ff false
```

However, whenever I update my current branch/pull from the remote, it creates a merge commit... which is really gross, especially for forking other projects on *GitHub*.

Is there anyway to make a `git pull` **always** fast-forward?
Unfortunately, I tried doing:

```
git pull --ff-only upstream master
```

... only to watch it spit out an error:

```
fatal: You cannot combine --no-ff with --ff-only.
```

I'm really tired of seeing this:

[image: Gross: a "git pull" merge commit]

Comment: What happens when you override the global setting locally in your repository via `git config merge.ff true`?

Comment: 1) I don't want to change the behavior of my other merges (non-pulls)
2) I don't want to have to change this for each repo I create/work-in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

This will rebase your commits on top of upstream commits.

Here is an illustration of what it does.

Your local repository:

```
* bbbbbbb (HEAD, master) My changes.
* aaaaaaa Initial commit.
```

Upstream repository:

```
* ccccccc (upstream/master) Their changes.
* aaaaaaa Initial commit.
```

After `git pull --rebase upstream master`:

```
* bbbbbbb (HEAD, master) My changes.
* ccccccc (upstream/master) Their changes.
* aaaaaaa Initial commit.
```

Comment: Damn. I was worried that I wouldn't be able to use my current flow. Thank you for this, however rebasing constantly just feels dirty.

Comment: @Rican7 it needs you to watch your step a little bit, but you get a way clearer tree. I've adopted it after being a `--no-ff` user...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to work in a separate branch and keep rebasing onto the remote branch instead of merging.

Change:

```
$ git checkout -b my-topic-branch
$ (work work work)
$ git commit
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
$ git merge my-topic-branch
```

By:

```
$ git checkout -b my-topic-branch
$ (work work work)
$ git commit
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase origin/master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge my-topic-branch
```

If that combination of configurations don't work, I think you're left with that.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to stay away from revising, but I appreciate the help. :-)